# Groebner basis reference request

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, groebner-basis

Someone recommended Eisenbud's Section 15 to me, but I am finding it to be a little too terse. Does anyone know of a fairly self-contained introduction to the topic? I am just now finishing up a graduate level course on ring and field theory, so I am at least familiar with the basic ring theoretic concepts.

Comment: Dummit and Foote section 9.6 was useful for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a longer exposition, you could try Cox, Little and O'Shea's book *Ideals, Varieties, Algorithms.*

This book contains a treatment of Grobner bases and a handful of variations on the Buchberger algorithm as it pertains to affine and projective algebraic geometry, with applications to topics like elimination theory and robotics.

Answer (score 0):

2nd *Ideals Varieties, and Algorithms.* Cox, Little, and O'Shea's followup *Using Algebraic Geometry* is also a good  reference that includes more advanced topics than IVA, such as Groebner bases for modules over polynomial rings, Groebner fan, and Groebner walks.